# How to remove characters after space in java

Tags: java

How can I do this in Java or Android like:

```
String name = "Jhon Doe";
textView.setText("Hi " + name);
// I want only "Jhon" not "Doe"
```

I want only first name ("Jhon") not last name ("Doe")

Comment: You may want to read [https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the java .split() function. It gives an array, with parts of the name, split by a space.

```
String name = "Jhon Doe";
String[] parts = string.split(" ");
textView.setText("Hi " + parts[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can try below code

```
String name = "Jhon Doe";
String[] separated = currentString.split("\\s+");
String name =  separated[0]; // this will contain "Jhon"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Java.String.split()](https://www.baeldung.com/string/split)

```
String string = "Jhon Doe";
String[] parts = string.split(" ");
String name = parts[0]; // Jhon
String surname = parts[1]; // Doe
textView.setText("Hi " + name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it.

```
String name = "Jhon Doe";
textView.setText("Hi " + name.split(" ")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer regex why not

```
String firstName = "John Doe".replaceFirst("^(\\w+).*$","$1")
```

Have fun.